# React.js Can I use array.map within componentDidMount() on an array returned from an axios request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm making a foodtruck finder website and I'm running into an error.  My team is separating foodtrucks and foodtruck schedules so we have to make 2 different axios calls to get all our data.  Our issue is that we aren't getting our schedule from the backend but we are getting the foodtruck data. I'll provide the code:

```
 async componentDidMount(){
    // get the array of trucks
    let userData = await Request.findTrucksByOwnerID(this.state.ownerTruckID);

    this.setState({
        data: userData,
    });

    userData.map((truck) => {
    let scheduleData = await Request.getScheduleDTOByID(truck.id);
    this.setState({
        schedule: [...this.state.schedule, scheduleData]
    });


    });

    // get the array of schedules
    console.log(this.state.data);
  };
```

the functions called by Request

```
export async function findTrucksByOwnerID(id) {
  return await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: constants.backend_url + "trucks/findTrucksByOwnerID",
    params: { id: id },
    headers: request_headers,
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    });
}

export function getScheduleDTOByID(id) {
  return axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: constants.backend_url + "schedule/getScheduleDTOByID",
    params: { id: id },
    headers: request_headers,
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    });
}
```

Can I do Axios requests inside a map function the way I'm doing currently?  I'm very new to using React so any info would be appreciated!

Comment: The `userData.map` callback also needs to be an async function in order to await the fetches to resolve. Another common pattern is to load up all your asynchronous fetch requests into an array and `Promise.all` them, which when all request promises resolve yields you the array of resolved values you store in state.

Comment: @DrewReese could you provide an example or link me to an example?  that sounds like a good solution but I don't know how to write that

Comment: [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled). Promise.all resolves when all promises resolve, but if any of the axios fetch requests throw an error the entire promise rejects. Promise.allSettled returns an array of the results regardless if they rejected, so you'd need to iterate over the result to only operate on the successful calls. If you need more help I can try to get a demo up, but the docs are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to your comment. This is my suggested solution:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  // get the array of trucks
  let userData = await Request.findTrucksByOwnerID(this.state.ownerTruckID);

  const requests = userData.map(truck => Request.getScheduleDTOByID(truck.id));

  const listOfScheduleData = await Promise.all(requests);

  this.setState({
    // depends on if you want to keep original `this.state.schedule`

    // if you do:
    schedule: [...this.state.schedule, ...listOfScheduleData]

    // if you don't:
    schedule: listOfScheduleData
  });
}
```